# PdfBox: PDF/A-1A to PDF/A-3A

Tags: validation, pdf, pdf-generation, pdfbox, pdfa

i have the following problem:
i want to transform a PDF/A-1A document to a PDF/A-3A.
The original document is validated by Arobat Reader Pro, so i can asume it is PDF/A-1A conform.

I try to convert the PDF metadata with the following code:

```
private PDDocumentCatalog makeA3compliant(PDDocument doc) throws IOException, TransformerException  {
PDDocumentCatalog cat = doc.getDocumentCatalog();
PDMetadata metadata = new PDMetadata(doc);
cat.setMetadata(metadata);

XMPMetadata xmp = new XMPMetadata();
XMPSchemaPDFAId pdfaid = new XMPSchemaPDFAId(xmp);
xmp.addSchema(pdfaid);

XMPSchemaDublinCore dc = xmp.addDublinCoreSchema();
String creator = "TestCr";
String producer = "testPr";
dc.addCreator(creator);
dc.setAbout("");

XMPSchemaBasic xsb = xmp.addBasicSchema();
xsb.setAbout("");
xsb.setCreatorTool(creator);
xsb.setCreateDate(GregorianCalendar.getInstance());

PDDocumentInformation pdi = new PDDocumentInformation();
pdi.setProducer(producer);
pdi.setAuthor(creator);
doc.setDocumentInformation(pdi);

XMPSchemaPDF pdf = xmp.addPDFSchema();
pdf.setProducer(producer);
pdf.setAbout("");

PDMarkInfo markinfo = new PDMarkInfo();
markinfo.setMarked(true);
doc.getDocumentCatalog().setMarkInfo(markinfo);

pdfaid.setPart(3);
pdfaid.setConformance("A");
pdfaid.setAbout("");

metadata.importXMPMetadata(xmp);

return cat;
```

}

If i try to validate the new file with Acrobat again, i get a validation error:

> CIDset in subset font is incomplete (font contains glyphs that are not listed)

if i try to validate the file with this online validator (http://www.pdf-tools.com/pdf/validate-pdfa-online.aspx) it is a valid PDF/A-3A....

am i missing something?

is nobody able to help?

EDIT: Here is the [PDF file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tn9lxud72l2xuxc/test_pdfa3a_1436134559799.pdf?dl=0)

Comment: You're missing the PDF file.

Comment: It's impossible to say much about your problem if we don't have the PDF file to examine...

Comment: I added a link to the PDF file

Comment: @TilmanHausherr thanks for your comment, i added the generated pdf some days ago

Comment: @DavidvanDriessche thanks for your comment, i added the generated pdf some days ago

Comment: I looked at the file with PDFBox preflight (which checks PDF/A-1b) and it didn't any any problems except the ones I'd expect (i.e. that the xml is not for A-1b).

Comment: I've looked at your file with callas pdfToolbox (I'm associated with this tool); this is the same technology as what is integrated in Acrobat. You're correct that PDF/A-1a does NOT and PDF/A-3a DOES give an error. The problem is caused by a font and there is indeed a difference between the two profiles that could explain the difference. I'm actually going to report this to callas and see whether it's a bug in the software or whether there's an actual difference between the two flavours of the standard that could explain this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for us to be fully PDF/A-3 compliant regarding the CIDset issue:

```java
private void removeCidSet(PDDocumentCatalog catalog) {

  COSName cidSet = COSName.getPDFName("CIDSet");

  // iterate over all pdf pages
  for (Object object : catalog.getAllPages()) {
    if (object instanceof PDPage) {

      PDPage page = (PDPage) object;
      Map<String, PDFont> fonts = page.getResources().getFonts();
      Iterator<String> iterator = fonts.keySet().iterator();

      // iterate over all fonts
      while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        PDFont pdFont = fonts.get(iterator.next());

        if (pdFont instanceof PDType0Font) {
          PDType0Font typedFont = (PDType0Font) pdFont;

          if (typedFont.getDescendantFont() instanceof PDCIDFontType2Font) {
            PDCIDFontType2Font f = (PDCIDFontType2Font) typedFont.getDescendantFont();
            PDFontDescriptor fontDescriptor = f.getFontDescriptor();

            if (fontDescriptor instanceof PDFontDescriptorDictionary) {
              PDFontDescriptorDictionary fontDict = (PDFontDescriptorDictionary) fontDescriptor;
              fontDict.getCOSDictionary().removeItem(cidSet);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

OK - I think I have an answer on your question from the perspective of the callas and/or Adobe technology *(and once more, I'm affiliated with callas and its pdfToolbox technology that is also used inside of Acrobat)*.

According to my research and the people I consulted, your example PDF document contains a font with a CID character set that is incomplete. Why does pdfToolbox or Acrobat say it's a valid PDF/A-1a file but not a valid PDF/A-3a file? Interesting question:

1) The rules for incomplete CID sets *changed* between PDF/A-1a and PDF/A-3a. They are *stricter* in PDF/A-3a.

2) But while in PDF/A-1a a CID set always had to be there, in PDF/A-3a you can have a valid, compliant file, without such a CID set.

So, your PDF file contains a CID set (which makes it valid for PDF/A-1a and A-3a) but while that CID set is fine for A-1a it **does not** contains all characters to be A-3a compliant.

To test at least part of this theory, I processed your file through pdfToolbox with a fixup entitled "Remove CIDset if incomplete". That correction (as the name implies) removes the CID set from the file but doesn't change anything else. After doing so your file validates as a valid A-3a file.

That leaves the question why the pdftools web site claims this is a valid PDF/A-3a file; according to the people I've spoken to, the result from preflight for this file is correct and there should be an error on this file. So perhaps that's something you need to take up with the pdftools guys (and they possibly with callas to figure out who's finally right).

Feel free to send me a personal message if you want to discuss this further - more discussion on the tools themselves probably becomes off-topic for this public site.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! It is very helpful!
My problem is, I want to generate a valid PDF/A-3A.
Like you said, the solving step would be to remove incomplete CIDsets.
I'm trying to that with PDFBox, without success till now, I will write if i find a solution.