Error in PDF Validation with Mustang: A CIDSet entry in the Font descriptor does not correctly identify all glyphs present in the embedded font subset
I am using JasperReports to generate PDF documents and attempting to validate them with the Mustang library via
ZUGFeRDValidator validator = new ZUGFeRDValidator();
return validator.validate("./mypdf.pdf");

However, I encounter the following error: "A CIDSet entry in the Font descriptor does not correctly identify all glyphs present in the embedded font subset."
I am using the following libraries:

JasperReports Version: 6.21.3
Mustang Validator Version: 2.11.0
PDFBox Version: 3.0.2

Here is the code I use to create pdfs:
generate(JasperReport report, Map<String,Object> data, OutputStream document) {
            [...]
            JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, data, new JREmptyDataSource());
            JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
            exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(print));
            exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(document));

            SimplePdfExporterConfiguration exportConfig = new SimplePdfExporterConfiguration();
            exportConfig.setPdfVersion(PdfVersionEnum.VERSION_1_7);
            exportConfig.setPdfaConformance(PdfaConformanceEnum.PDFA_3B);
            exportConfig.setIccProfilePath("AdobeRGB1998.icc");
            exportConfig.setMetadataAuthor("Your Name");
            exportConfig.setTagged(true);
            exportConfig.setTagLanguage("en-us");
            exportConfig.setEmbedIccProfile(true);

            exporter.setConfiguration(exportConfig);
            exporter.exportReport();

            [...]
}

The fonts that I'm using are OpenSans fonts:
In my fontsfamily.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fontFamilies>
    <fontFamily name="OpenSans">
        <!-- Normal Font -->
        <normal><![CDATA[fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf]]></normal>
        <!-- Bold Font -->
        <bold><![CDATA[fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf]]></bold>
        <!-- Italic Font -->
        <italic><![CDATA[fonts/OpenSans-Italic.ttf]]></italic>
        <!-- Bolt italic Font -->
        <boldItalic><![CDATA[fonts/OpenSans-BoldItalic.ttf]]></boldItalic>
        <!-- Is font is embedded in PDF -->
        <pdfEmbedded><![CDATA[true]]></pdfEmbedded>
    </fontFamily>
</fontFamilies>

In my jasperreports_extension.properties:
net.sf.jasperreports.extension.registry.factory.fonts=net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontExtensionsRegistryFactory
net.sf.jasperreports.extension.simple.font.families.OpenSans=fonts/fontsfamily.xml

I suspected that there might be an issue with how I embed the font, so here are my attempts:

I have ensured that the fonts are embedded as subsets by using the isPdfEmbedded attribute like this:

<style name="Standard" isDefault="true" pattern="" fontName="OpenSans" fontSize="10" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>

The pdf acrobat reader also shows in the font properties that a subset of the font is embedded.

The error also occurs when I comment out all text from the .jrxml report template, leaving only the font styles embedded.

I tried out another font as well (DejaVu Sans), to see if OpenSans is the problem but it didn't work either.


What else can I do to try fixing this error?
EDIT
I totally tunnelvisioned and overlooked the fact that there are more than this error. The validation also shows that xmp Metadata are not valid:
<error type="11">XMP Metadata: ConformanceLevel not found</error>  
<error type="12">XMP Metadata: ConformanceLevel contains invalid value</error>  
<error type="13">XMP Metadata: DocumentType not found</error>  
<error type="14">XMP Metadata: DocumentType invalid</error>  
<error type="21">XMP Metadata: DocumentFileName not found</error>  
<error type="19">XMP Metadata: DocumentFileName contains invalid value</error>  
<error type="15">XMP Metadata: Version not found</error>  
<error type="16">XMP Metadata: Version contains invalid value</error> 

But still the Error above may be unrelated to the font Error.
Here is a sample output.pdf to validate with mustang. It is a blank page without text and it still gives the error. I reduced the example to only importing the font via the  tag and nothing more.
EDIT 2
I was able to remove the CIDSet and the validation said that the pdf is compliant. Here is the code:
            for (PDPage page : document.getPages()) {
                for (COSName fontName : page.getResources().getFontNames()) {
                    PDFont font = page.getResources().getFont(fontName);
                    if (font instanceof PDType0Font) {
                        PDType0Font type0Font = (PDType0Font) font;
                        PDCIDFont descendantFont = (PDCIDFont) type0Font.getDescendantFont();
                        if (type0Font.getDescendantFont() instanceof PDCIDFontType2) {
                            PDCIDFontType2 f = (PDCIDFontType2) type0Font.getDescendantFont();
                            PDFontDescriptor fontDescriptor = f.getFontDescriptor();

                            if (fontDescriptor instanceof PDFontDescriptor) {
                                PDFontDescriptor fontDict = (PDFontDescriptor) fontDescriptor;
                                fontDict.setCIDSet(null);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }


Even though it feels a bit cumbersome because it requires you to convert the document to a PDDocument, this solution works.
I will let this post open, maybe we will find a simpler solution in the future.

@KJ Thank you for your feedback. I totally overlooked and tunnelvisioned at the fact that there are more errors to the validation (I updated my post accordingly). Still I provided an output.pdf as an example where I reduced it that has no content whatsoever. That means the error comes with or without the font in the pdf. But other than that I will try to fix the other errors first...

This is a low level PDF error, there is nothing you can do to fix it. The module responsible with PDF generation (PDFBox or Jasper) must fix it.

@KJ Thank you for this information. So according to this message, it seems that the CIDSet's length is just 1 which is faulty. Any suggestions how I can go about this problem? The isPdfEmbedded attribute, omitting text or changing the font itself did not work either.

@iPDFdev ok, well so then I try to open up an issue. Thank you

I hard-changed that PDF to be PDF/A-1b and it passes the VeraPDF check. The embedded font has 938 entries, and CIDSet definitively not.

I tried to reproduce it with PDFBox 3.0.2 and it validated if I had a text. The validation failed if there was no text, i.e. if like in your file the font was used but no text with it. However the embedded font didn't have countless blank glyphs like in your PDF.

The PDF/A-3 file passes if I remove the CIDSet entry when there's only CID 0. However the same file fails as PDF/A-1 because there the CIDSet entry is mandatory so I can't change PDFBox. Oh, and I see that Mustang uses VeraPDF. It would be interesting if the file validates with Adobe.

@TilmanHausherr thank you for your input and your efforts! Unfortunately, I need to produce a PDF/A-3B file and I want to do it with jasperreports. I have also tried another pdf where I wrote a simple text "This is a test" as content, so I do not only have a blank page. But again, when I validate this with Mustang I get the same Error as stated in the post :/.

@KJ Thank you! I see the pdf that you provided when it is validated undoubtedly has no error. However in the document properties, it is because there is no font embedded. I just provided a blank page as smallest pdf example to demonstrate, as soon as a font is embedded, the error will be thrown validated by mustang. I need fonts, contents and text in my reports. My goal at the end is to create a PDF/A-3B that is valid as ZUGFeRD file. I also created a github issue: https://github.com/TIBCOSoftware/jasperreports/issues/457

@KJ Ok I understnad now better. So I take away that there are three options where the mistake may lie in: 1. I don't know how to insert a font properly into a jasper reports template. 2. Jasper Reports/pdfbox itself injects the fonts incorrectly or 3. The fonts that I am using have bad euro definitions?

Sadly I don't know who is to blame. I looked at your file and the embedded font doesn't look like the embedding that PDFBox is creating. However I also found a possible issue with either PDFBox or VeraPDF. After a lot of reading the PDF specification I opened a ticket with VeraPDF: https://github.com/veraPDF/veraPDF-library/issues/1462  However this doesn't fix your issue. That one could be fixed by removing the /CIDSet: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31209981/

"I looked at your file and the embedded font doesn't look like the embedding that PDFBox is creating. " - According to the Info data the producer is "OpenPDF 1.3.32", so in regards to the code that produced this embedding, you should look here.

Thank you all. I tried to remove the CIDSet and validated it with mustang and it finally says that the pdf is compliant! Thank you @TilmanHausherr for your advice. Appreciate your efforts.

I was so focused on that font that I forgot to look at /Info ‍♂️. In the meantime VeraPDF has admitted its mistake. OpenPDF (which is an itext fork) has a setting to not include CIDSet: https://github.com/LibrePDF/OpenPDF/issues/1041 but this must be done by Jasper I guess. You could of course also create an issue with your file, they botched the font subsetting. Anyway, that was an interesting question, it ended up finding bugs in two products, not the ones suspected

Wow, very interesting results! Indeed, this has been quite a journey :D I am a PDF noob. Could you please elaborate on what you mean by forgetting to look at /Info? And in which way did they botch the font subsetting? Does that have to do with the CIDSet?

@OhJohnny The /CIDSet stream is mandatory for PDF/A-1b but not for PDF/A-3b so they could just remove it for PDF/A-3b. The botched subsetting, see my comment "The embedded font has 938 entries, and CIDSet definitively not." The embedded font should have only 1 entry instead of 938 of which 937 were empty. Or they would have to fix the /CIDSet stream so it has 938 entries too. PDF devs will understand this.

Thank you guys so much, it is all much clearer now!
